# Ошибка с выводом списка

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

Использую linked list в Си. В определенный момент заполняю данные в структуру. Появилась потребность вывести весь заполненный лист. Но получил в результате странное поведение. Прошу помочь так как запутался, в си не силен.
Структура `Recipe`:

```
typedef  struct Recipe {
    char *title;
    ...
}Recipe;
```

Структура `data:`

```
typedef struct data{
    int count;
    void *containe_data;
    struct data * next;
} data;
```

где `containe_data` в результате выполнения программы преобразуется в `Recipe`.
Есть переменная `data *Recipes` которая хранит рецепты. 
Добавление происходит так:

```
Recipe recipe;
recipe.title = strdup(title);
...
Recipes = add_data(&recipe);
```

Вывожу список так:

```
void print_recipes(data* recipes){
    data *start = recipes;

    for (;start != NULL; start = start -> next){
        Recipe *printRecipe = (Recipe*)start -> containe_data;
        printf("title - %s\n", printRecipe -> title);
    }
}
```

Код `linked list:`

```
data *start = NULL;
data *last = NULL;
data *next = NULL;

data* create_data(void *input_data){

    data *i = (data*) malloc(sizeof(data));
    i -> containe_data = input_data;
    i -> next = NULL;
    return i;
}

data* add_data(void *data){

    next = create_data(data);

    if (start == NULL){
        start = next;
    }

    if (last != NULL){
        last -> next = next;
        last -> count++;
    }
    last = next;
    return start;
}

int getCount(data *head){
    data* current = head;
    int count = 0;

    while(current != NULL){
        current++;
    }
    return count;
}

data* get(data *head, int x){
    data* current = head;
    int count = 0;

    if (x < 0){
        printf("Invalid index passes\n");
    }

    while(current != NULL){
        if (count == x){
            return current;
        }
        count++;
        current = current -> next;
    }
    return NULL;
}

void mem_free(data *text){
    //free memory

    data *start = text;
    data *next = NULL;

    for (; start != NULL; start = next){
        next = start -> next;
        free(start -> containe_data);
        free(start);
    }
}
```

В результате получаю лишь последнее значение, остольное с мусором.

```
title - 222
title - �t�����tp�-)��E-)��t:���-)��tk��Y
title - �t�����tp�-)��E-)��t:���-)��tk��Y
```

Comment: Лучше привести полный пример, который компилируется, но не работает. Потому что иначе сложно сказать, виновата ли строка `Recipe recipe;

Recipes = add_data(&recipe);`, но скорее всего виновата

Comment: @KoVadim, спасибо за подсказку. С Recipe *recipe = malloc(sizeof(Recipe); все заработало. Но все равно интересно почему так выходило.

Comment: опять же, на уровне догадки. Похоже, Вы передавали адрес структуры, которая умирала после выхода из области видимости. И когда уже ее печатали, то адреса были в пустоту.